# How can I make a Minecraft server?

Tags: games

I have Minecraft and it works perfectly but I want to make a server so I can play with my friends. I tried doing it the way you would do it for Mac OS but it won't work. Is there a specific way for elementary OS?

Comment: You'd likely have more luck looking for instructions for Ubuntu than OS X, Googling that should give you an answer appropriate for here.

Comment: Are you trying to create a dedicated server with the server edition of Minecraft or just create a LAN world? Can you explain what you mean by "won't work"? What exactly doesn't work? Do you get any error messages or erratic behavior?

Answer (score 7):

You can host your server like this:

- Create a directory for your server.
  `cd && mkdir Server`
- Change your active directory to the new folder.
  `cd Server`
- Let's download the latest minecraft server (in this case 1.8.8).
  `wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/1.8.8/minecraft_server.1.8.8.jar -O minecraft_server.jar`
- We need to have openjre installed (you probably already have this for the mc client).
  `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`
- Create a bash script to run your server.
  `touch server.sh && chmod +x server.sh`
- Time to edit our script
  `scratch-text-editor server.sh`

Paste this and save

```
#!/bin/bash -       
#title           :server.sh
#===================================

java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

- Run our server with:
  `./server.sh`

You'll have to agree with the EULA but since you've already done it under Mac I'll trust you don't need help with that.

Under normal operation, just `cd Server` and `./server.sh`

Comment: Error: Unable to access jarfile minecraft_server.jar
That's what I get when I try to run It. I have it downloaded as well.

Comment: That happens when you are in the wrong folder. Use pwd to see where you are, and follow with ls and check if minecraft_server is in that directory, server.sh and Minecraftserver must be in the same directory, and so must you when you run the command